# UIImage to YUV 422 Colorspace

Tags: objective-c, image-processing, ios4, uiimage, yuv

I have been trying to figure this out for a while to no avail, I was wondering if someone could help or point me in he right direction.

I have a need to convert an UIImage or a stored JPG to get its YUV422 data so I can then apply some image enhancements, and with the result convert it back to either a JPG or UIImage.

I'm a bit stuck at the moment, I this point I am just trying to get it to YUV422.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must first read the JPEG markers to determine the meta data. The meta data such as the size, the sample rate (usually 4:2:2 but not always ), the quantization tables, and the huffman tables.

You must then de-huffman-code the entropy encoded data segment. This will give you DC coefficient followed by any AC coefficients for the color channel for each channel in zig zag form. you must then de zigzag the entries and multiply it by the corresponding quantization table. Finally you must preform the Inverse Discrete Cosine Transformation on the decoded macroblock.

This will then give you 3 channels in YCrCb (YUV is for analog) at the sample rate the JPEG was encoded at. If you need it to be 4:2:2 you will have to resample.

Hopefully you have a library to do the actual JPEG decoding since writing one that is compliant is a non trivial task.

Here is a very basic and *flawed* JPEG decoder I started writing to give you more technical details. [Ruby JPEG decoder](https://github.com/ChrisLundquist/Ruby-Image-Library/blob/master/jpeg.rb) It does not successfully implement the IDCT

For a correct implementation in C [I suggest IJG](http://www.ijg.org/)

Comment: JPEG images are almost always 4:2:0, meaning both horizontal and vertical chroma resolution is halved. 4:2:2 means only the horizontal resolution is halved.